# rotate 3D sphere around itself - webGL

Tags: unity, opengl, javascript, webgl

I'm trying to build 3D solar system with webGL.
I have all the stars moving in a circle around the sun as sholud be, and I want them also to spin around their own Y axis.

How can I add it?
 I tried :

```
mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(starsList[i].Yangle), [1, 0, 0]);
```

but I got wierd result.
any help?

```
mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [0, 0, -30]);

for (i = 0; i < starsList.length; i++) {  
    mvPushMatrix();
    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(starsList[i].angle), [0, 1, 0]);
    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(starsList[i].Yangle), [1, 0, 0]);

    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, starsList[i].initPlace);
    mvPopMatrix(); 
 }


var lastTime = 0;

function animate() {
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    if (lastTime != 0) {
        var elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;
        for (i = 0; i < starsList.length; i++) { 
            starsList[i].angle += starsList[i].speed * elapsed;
            starsList[i].Yangle += starsList[i].speed * elapsed;

        }
    }
    lastTime = timeNow;
}
```

Comment: Rotate them before you apply the transformations